# Composition of quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Consider the following two quadratic forms on $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$Q(x, y, z)=\lambda x^2+4y^2+16z^2$, $R(x, y, z)=2xy+2yz$

Determine precisely those values of $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ such that there's a linear transformation $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that $R=Q\circ T$

By some direct computation, I've found out that if such a linear $T$ exists then

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=T^t\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & 0\\
0 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 16
\end{bmatrix}T$

But then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I've edited my question to show what I've done

Comment: I wouldn’t proceed in that way. See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3802413/finding-quadratic-forms-of-a-certain-kind-that-are-the-composition-of-a-given-qu